# awk or sed command to split large text file matching a regex into smaller files each containing n records

Tags: sed, awk

I want to split a text file into multiple files based on the matched regex. This is straight forward using awk.
for instance,

```
tmp_file_prefix="f-" ; awk '/^ID:/{x="'"$tmp_file_prefix"'" ++i;} {print > x;}' file.txt
```

The catch is, the input text file "file.txt" is huge in size, 2.6 GB to be precise.
I'm sure, I'll quickly run out of max file limit in a directory.

The above awk command does my job well and splits the file containing the entire record matching the regex into multiple files. I've executed the command on a smaller sized file with 25 such records each with varied sizes. But I realized that this will overrun the limit of max files in a directory.

I tried the following pattern:

```
tmp_file_prefix="f-" ; awk -v i=0 '/^ID:/{x="'"$tmp_file_prefix"'" ++i;} i % 20 == 0 {print > x;}' file.txt
```

and realized that it emits only the 20th pattern and saves the same in the file. This solution is incorrect.

I want a way in the above said awk command whereby I can split the source file into smaller files, each containing 25000 thousand (or n for that matter) occurrences of the regex.

Comment: I think NitzanShaked has the best answer. One note about your awk use though: pass shell variables into awk with the `-v` option. Then you don't have to jump through quoting hoops: `awk -v prefix="$tmp_file_prefix" '/^ID:/{x = prefix ++i;} {print > x;}' file`

Comment: Sameer: From your description it sounds like you only want to extract _matching_ lines, but your first `awk` command outputs ALL lines, because `{ print > x; }` is a *separate* action (without a preceding pattern) and thus is processed for ALL input lines (effectively, you're extracting *blocks* of lines _starting_ with the matching one).

Answer (score 2):

`grep '^ID:' file.txt | split -l 25000`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -v prefix="$tmp_file_prefix" -v max=25000 '
    function filename() { return sprintf(%s%06d", prefix, ++i) }
    !x { x = filename() }
    /^ID:/ {
        print > x
        n++
        if (n == max) {
            close x
            x = ""
            n = 0
        }
    }
' file
```

This should not run out of open file handles, as it takes care to close the file when done.

Comment: You're missing the `{print > x;}` block (the OP is trying to split into *blocks* of lines *starting* with a line matching `^ID:`, not just the  ID lines themselves). The conscientious closing of files is great, but the OP seems concerned about the max. _number of files in a directory_.

Comment: I think you're wrong. The question says "split the source file into smaller files, each containing 25000 thousand (or n for that matter) occurrences of the regex." So OP only wants regex matches in the resulting files. @sameer, please confirm

Comment: The original `awk` command is what led me to conclude it's about blocks, but you're right - the text suggests otherwise. Your `awk` program is great; is it just an alternative to @NitzanShaked's simpler `grep` solution, or does it offer advantages over it (beyond the ability to easily turn it into a 'blocky' solution)?

Comment: IMO, it's just an awk translation of Nitzan's superior (and no doubt faster) solution. The main point is that a large file can be processed in awk without running out of open file handles.

Comment: A little clearer: The pattern search in my first awk command gives me a record that starts from string "ID:" on the first column. This record has a plain text arranged in free flow form and has other text and new-lines, etc.. My first awk command does my job very well. It fetches each record and places each found record in different file where each file has a separate record. The problem is it'll generate huge number of files outnumbering 200,000. Also, little of my bad. Expected no. of records per file should be 25000 and not 25000 thousand. The latter evaluates to 25 million :).

Comment: Please show some sample text and how the output files should look.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the source file into smaller pieces first using **split (1)**, then run your awk script on each piece. Obviously you will need to append to the output files, not overwrite them!

```
split -l 25000 -a 3 file.txt
```

will generate files xaaa, xaab, xaac etc., each no more than 25000 lines long, which you can then process with your awk script

Comment: `alias mysplitl='_(){ (($#<1)) && echo "Usage: <file name> <lines>" && return;SUFFIX="${1##*.}"; split --additional-suffix=".${SUFFIX}" -d --lines="${2:-500}" "${1}" "${1%.*}_"; }; _'`