# Split a huge csv based on time intervals depending on inner text tags

Tags: python, r, csv, split, intervals

I have a huge ".csv" file which corresponds to an one-day data file.
Every half-hour of the day, data was recorded during ten minutes. In the file, each half-hour is separated by a text tag, such as "zzzz" or "system sleep", depending on the .csv.

I would like to split the CSV breaking it into the 48 half-hour blocks, and save each half-hour .csv in a new foder that includes 48 smaller csv. files. I am sure there are ways to do this but I cannot find the way. Because each half-hour values do not have exactly the same number of rows, I cannot split this data according to row numbers.

The file will look something like the following (I made a shortened example):

| ID | Day | Time | Rec | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:00 | 1 | 251 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:01 | 2 | 368 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:02 | 3 | 430 |
| system sleep. |  |  |  |  |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:30 | 1 | 195 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:31 | 2 | 876 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 00:32 | 3 | 864 |
| system sleep. |  |  |  |  |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 01:00 | 1 | 872 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 01:01 | 2 | 120 |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 01:02 | 3 | 208 |
| system sleep. |  |  |  |  |
| (...) | (...) | (...) | (...) | (...) |
| A1 | 2018/1/30 | 23:39 | 10 | 002 |

And so it goes for the whole day. Please note my actual data has up to 7000 values per half-hour*.

I would like to split it for each "system sleep" (or each time such text appears in the first column); and save the new .csv files in a new folder. Also, if possible, I would like to keep the header (first row) for all the half-hour blocks/new csv'. Ideally, I'd also like the file to be saved after the first time value/row of each block ("Time") -but I guess it would still work if it was saved as 1, 2, 3, 4.

Can anyone help me? I usually work with R language, but if it's easily done in another language such as python (I found many answers in python but not exaclty what I need), I wouldn't mind giving it a try eventhough I have no experience with it (but if I know R, it should be doable). Thank you very much..!

Comment: hint: have a look at the `cumsum` function, e.g.  generate a group column to split by, e.g.`cumsum(DF$ID=="system sleep.")`. You could obviously also use more appropriate commands in unix/linux if the file is huge, e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578668/awk-or-sed-command-to-split-large-text-file-matching-a-regex-into-smaller-files

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to use the function
`which(startsWith(df$treeID, "system sleep."))`,
this retrieved me all the columns that started with this value.
Then using the function `slice` and the previous column I can cut the dataframe. However, I can only do it one by one (selecting with [1], [2], etc. the row and slicing the rest). So I am trying to build a loop now.
If you want more details send me a message.
Thank you.